# Where does the home icon of the site come from?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wonder where the home icon of the page [www.w3schools.com/cssref](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref) comes from (the icon marked by the upper left red circle in the image below) ?

[image: webpage]

I inspected the element by chrome browser:

```
<a href="/default.asp" class="topnav-icons fa fa-home w3-left w3-bar-item w3-button" title="Home"></a>
```

However, in the css classes I can't find anything that creates/displays the icon. I also observed: If the page is saved by chrome (or firefox) then the icon is missing:

[image: webpage saved]

That indicates that the icon is dynamically associated, by I can't find the place.

**Question:** Where does the home icon eventually come from ?

Comment: from an icon font file

Comment: The `fa-` class prefix indicates that it comes from https://fontawesome.com/ It uses the `::before` CSS pseudo element to display a character, with a font containing the icons

Comment: Google "glyphicon" for more information and examples.  "Halflings" is a popular icon font that ships with bootstrap.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use the Web Inspector (good things are not told by W3Schools, so don't follow it), you can clearly see it's a `::before` pseudo class:

[image: fontawesome]

It is by `font-awesome` font and you can find all the font icons here: [FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/).

When you are saving in Chrome, you won't be able to get the following:

- Background Images
- Images referred by CSS
- Embedded HTML objects
- Videos

Also, `font-awesome` fonts work by using the `content` attribute.

Comment: specifically the `content` property

Comment: Haha, this alone would be an upvote: `good things are not told by W3Schools, so don't follow it`

Comment: @Martijn Ha ha ha.